# Vue js with simple JavaScript Vue is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to understand how vue works. To do that I simplify it as much as possible, hence no webpack no CDNs or any other packages (unless its a necessity).

So, Came up with this but trying to inject a simple a variable into html gives vue is undefined error.

*vue.js file is taken from npm vue package.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="vue.js"></script>

  <script>
  new vue({
    data: 'This must be injected'
  }).$mount('#app');
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p> {{ data }} </p>
  </div>

  <h1>This is a sample header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `new Vue` (uppercase "V")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have Vue load after the Dom is ready so it can find the element to attach itself to — don't put it in the head. Also it's upper-case `Vue`. And `Data` can't just be a naked property it should be a function that returns an object with your properties (it can also be an an object, [but it's not recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) once the app starts getting bigger).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <p> {{ data }} </p>

</div>

<h1>This is a sample header</h1>
<script>
  Vue.config.productionTip = false
  new Vue({
    data(){ return {
      data: 'This must be injected'
    }
  }
  }).$mount('#app');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code.

1. vue should be Vue
2. data should be an Object or Function - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

```html
<html>
<head>  
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">

    <p> {{ myText }} </p>

  </div>

  <h1>This is a sample header</h1>

  <script src="vue.js"></script>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      data: {
        myText: 'This must be injected'
      }
    }).$mount('#app');

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this will not work since you're placing that script inside head element

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the data must have an object as it's value.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="vue.js"></script>

<script>

new Vue({
  data: {
     txt: 'This must be injected'
  }
}).$mount('#app');

</script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app">

  <p> {{ txt }} </p>

  </div>

  <h1>This is a sample header</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```